# ListBox items empty when generated client-side

Tags: c#, listbox, asp.net-3.5

I'm adding items like this:

```
$('#listbox').append('<option value="1">"1"</option>');
```

On the server-side `listbox.Items` are ALWAYS empty. How do I get the values added by client-side script?

I'm using C# ASP .Net 3.5

Answer (score 0):

What you've shown is pure client-side javascript.  You are only adding HTML markup that allows the user to select values.  This will never affect the content of the server-side controls.  The selected values will be returned in the form collection for the corresponding input field.

If you want to add them on the server side, you must add them prior to rendering the page using ASP code, e.g.,

```
<asp:ListBox id="listbox" 
       Rows="6"
       Width="100px"
       SelectionMode="Single" 
       runat="server">

     <asp:ListItem>Item 1</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem>Item 2</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem>Item 3</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem>Item 4</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem>Item 5</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem>Item 6</asp:ListItem>

</asp:ListBox>
```

This will populate the select list for you and the options will be bound to the `listbox` control.

Comment: I know that. But that's not where the problem is. I have an textbox where the user can input text. This text is then added to the ListBox. I need to get these added info from the listbox on the server-side. One solution is pure javascript based where I can send the data through a manual doPostBack. I am just wondering if there are other ways.

Comment: No, there is no way to alter the server-side content without a call back to the server.  You can do that by submitting the page via POST or with an AJAX HTTP request call, but either way you are sending data back to the server and will need to insert the necessary logic on the server-side.